# Stuck on page in install process (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, startup

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and Linux in general and I am having extreme trouble installing Xubuntu on my computer. The computer I am attempting to install on is a Gateway with Windows XP Home Edition 2002 Service Pack 3 and has an Intel Pentium 4 processor. The CD I have with Xubuntu on works perfectly fine, and I know this because I have tested it on another machine. Everything works fine until I select what I want to do from the booted disk. After selecting "Install Xubuntu" I am brought to a terminal-like area in which I cannot type that lists what I believe to be system functions. (e.g. [5.764016] note: kthrotld[36] exited with preempt_count 3, or Code: Bad EIP value.) I am stuck at this area and am forced to then turn off my computer manually. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

From the bit of googling I did, it seems this is often a hardware issue.  If you can try disabling all the onboard devices you can in the BIOS and install that way.

Then if it works you can re-enable them one at a time.  And the one that results in a kernel panic was the unsupported device.

I had a similar issue on FreeBSD with my HP laptop relating to a firewire controller.

Comment: I disabled every device except for the CD drive and the same thing occurred as previously did.

Comment: Then it's unsupported hardware.